# Oracle Text Contains Search on Index with Single Char not working

Tags: oracle, text

I have a simple table called index_search created as:

```
BEGIN
 ctx_ddl.create_preference('my_pref', 'BASIC_WORDLIST');
 ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_pref', 'SUBSTRING_INDEX', 'YES');
 ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_pref', 'wildcard_maxterms', 0);
END;
/

CREATE TABLE my_index_search (search_tokens VARCHAR2(100));

CREATE INDEX my_index_search_ctx_idx01 ON
  my_index_search (
    search_tokens
  )
    INDEXTYPE IS ctxsys.context PARAMETERS ( 'Wordlist my_pref SYNC(ON COMMIT)' );

INSERT INTO my_index_search 
VALUES('A ABC/45/464587');

COMMIT;
```

My text query uses the contains operator and when I search for the string '**ABC/45/464587**', the row is returned:

```
 SELECT *
   FROM my_index_search i
  WHERE contains ( search_tokens, '%ABC/45/464587%', 1 ) > 0;
```

But when I search for the string '**A ABC/45/464587**', the row is not:

```
 SELECT *
   FROM my_index_search i
  WHERE contains ( search_tokens, '%A ABC/45/464587%', 1 ) > 0;
```

Why when I add in the full search string which includes a single character ('A' int this case) does the search not return the row?

Thanks in advance for any help.
Duncs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `'A'` is part of [the default stoplist](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/astopsup.htm#CCREF2295), so Oracle Text doesn't index it. You can't search for words in the stoplist. If you tried a different letter, it would work.

```
INSERT INTO my_index_search 
VALUES('B ABC/45/464587');
COMMIT;

SELECT *
   FROM my_index_search i
  WHERE contains ( search_tokens, '%B ABC/45/464587%', 1 ) > 0;
```

[More details](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCAPP/GUID-71087894-0C0B-42CF-B37E-064401C54545.htm#CCAPP9094). You can set a custom (empty by default) stoplist when you create your Context index:

```
begin
ctx_ddl.create_stoplist('mystop', 'BASIC_STOPLIST');
ctx_ddl.add_stopword('mystop', 'The');
end;
```

And add to your create index preference:

```
PARAMETERS ( 'Wordlist my_pref SYNC(ON COMMIT) Stoplist mystop' );
```

You can also replace a stoplist in an existing index, but you'll have to rebuild it.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. Can you define a blank stoplist by doing:

begin
ctx_ddl.create_stoplist('mystop', 'BASIC_STOPLIST');
end;

without adding any in?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can define a blank stoplist by doing

```
begin 
    ctx_ddl.create_stoplist('mystop', 'BASIC_STOPLIST');
end;
```