# CONTAINS in oracle returns all rows when it encounters A and D characters

Tags: oracle, full-text-search, contains

I have a table E_TRAPLC_N with below values in ADDRESS column

```
NARROW WATER CASTLE E
NARROW WATER CASTLE B
NARROW WATER CASTLE C
NARROW WATER CASTLE A
NARROW WATER CASTLE A
NARROW WATER CASTLE D
```

I am using CONTAINS operator for searching words. When I use below queries

```
SELECT ADDRESS FROM E_TRAPLC_N A 
WHERE contains (ADDRESS, UPPER ('NARROW WATER CASTLE D')) > 0;
SELECT ADDRESS FROM E_TRAPLC_N A 
WHERE contains (ADDRESS, UPPER ('NARROW WATER CASTLE A')) > 0;
```

It returns all rows

```
NARROW WATER CASTLE E
NARROW WATER CASTLE B
NARROW WATER CASTLE C
NARROW WATER CASTLE A
NARROW WATER CASTLE A
NARROW WATER CASTLE D
```

But this

```
SELECT ADDRESS FROM E_TRAPLC_N A 
WHERE contains (ADDRESS, UPPER ('NARROW WATER CASTLE B')) > 0;
```

returns only

```
NARROW WATER CASTLE B
```

and

```
SELECT ADDRESS FROM E_TRAPLC_N A 
WHERE contains (ADDRESS, UPPER ('NARROW WATER CASTLE C')) > 0;
```

returns only

```
NARROW WATER CASTLE C
```

and so on

```
SELECT ADDRESS FROM E_TRAPLC_N A 
WHERE contains (ADDRESS, UPPER ('NARROW WATER CASTLE E')) > 0;
```

returns only

```
NARROW WATER CASTLE E
```

Why is that when I use `contains (ADDRESS, UPPER ('NARROW WATER CASTLE A')) > 0` (or) `contains (ADDRESS, UPPER ('NARROW WATER CASTLE D')) > 0` is returning all rows instead of respective rows?

Comment: you're interestingly [right](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b70b4dc91dc9edcec80b8c6b9d58bec5) !

Answer (score 3):

'A' and 'D' are part of the English language stoplist. So they are not considered as other chars in the index search. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/ccref/oracle-text-supplied-stoplists.html#GUID-963AB8F0-6244-4D37-A1D9-4AAC2974BEA1) for the stop list
See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55594639/oracle-text-contains-search-on-index-with-single-char-not-working) for a discussion